# how can I get a simd subroutine in gfortran?

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran, simd

I am trying to deal with some calculation, and I am encountered with some problem when dealing with simd direcitves in gfortran in codeblocks in Windows 10. I composed the following codes as a simplified case of my problem in view of coding involved with simd.

```
  program test
    use module2_explicit_vector_simd
    implicit none
    integer(8) i, int_time, end_time, n
    parameter ( n = 40 )
    real(8),dimension(n)::value_0, value_1

    call system_clock(int_time)
    do i = 1, n
      call iteration_test1(1.5d5,value_0(i))
    end do
    call system_clock(end_time)
    write(*,*) sum(value_0)
    write(*,*) "Parallel:",(end_time - int_time)/100

    call system_clock(int_time)
    do i = 1, n
      call iteration_test(1.5d5,value_1(i))
    end do
    call system_clock(end_time)
    write(*,*) sum(value_1)
    write(*,*) "Sequential  program:",(end_time - int_time)/100

  end program test


  subroutine iteration_test(val_in,val_out)
    implicit none
    real(8) val_in, val_out, val_temp
    integer(8)::num,i
    val_temp = 0.d0
    num = 200000
    do i = 1, num
       val_temp = val_temp + real(i,8)
       if (val_temp .gt. 233333.) then
          val_temp = 233333.
       endif
       end do
       val_out = val_in + val_temp
       return
  end subroutine iteration_test


  module module2_explicit_vector_simd
   contains
     subroutine iteration_test1(val_in,val_out)
     !$omp declare simd(iteration_test1) uniform(val_in)
        implicit none
        real(8),intent(in)::val_in
        real(8),intent(out)::val_out
        real(8) val_temp
        integer(8)::num,i
        val_temp = 0.d0
        num = 200000
        do i = 1, num
          val_temp = val_temp + real(i,8)
          if (val_temp .gt. 233333.) then
            val_temp = 233333.
          endif
        end do
        val_out = val_in + val_temp
        return
     end subroutine iteration_test1
  end module module2_explicit_vector_simd
```

I have manually tried the compiler flags such as "-fopenmp-simd, -march=native, -msse4.2, -mavx" etc., but I failed to get a faster calculation when simd is "supposed to be" used.

Could anyone do me a favor, and tell me why?
Many thanks

Notice: I should not use automatic optimization, such as O1, O2, O3...

Comment: Welcome, I highly suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. You definitely *should* use one of the higher optimization `-O` levels. E.g. aat least `-O2`. If you have some particular reason why you cannot, please mention it.

Comment: Note that modules should always come *before* your main program, not after it. Maybe you have them in separate files? That is not necessary, the module and the program can be in a single file. But the module must appear before it is used. Also note that the magic number `8` in `real(8)` is ugly and not portable and that `0.d0` does not have to be the same kind as kind 8. Also, `233333.` is single precision, not double. Actually, you could just use integers `0` and `233333`.

Comment: Not clear which loop you want to vectorize?

Comment: Compilers are very clever in simd'izing. OpenMP simd directives probably only make difference in very non-trivial cases such as vectorizing over function calls.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Note that this is the case here: the OP tries to apply SIMD to the loop that contains the routine call. However, this is not because one put `simd` directives that the compiler is always able to generate efficient vectorized binary code (and I'm not even sure it will attempt to do so if `-O2` is not specified)

Comment: @PierU Thanks PierU. I am trying to do so with addional option -O2. In fact, what I want to vectorize is the subroutine "iteration_test". I got the idea from this link:  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/explicit-vector-programming-in-fortran.html. Let me try more before I send you more detail from futher trials.

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава. Yes, I will learn how to post questions in the following days, thanks for your kind remind. And for your comments:(1) OK, I will try the -O2 and -O2. What I  want to test is the difference of CPU time if simd is used or not. However, If I use -O2, both procedures will get almost same CPU time. (2) the module is composed in a seperate file. and (3)Oh yes, I will check the data type, make it accordence with single or double.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout. So may I ask you, that the vectorization of subroutine is not possible? I got the idea of vectorize subroutine in link https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/explicit-vector-programming-in-fortran.html, although that is given in ifort. I will try more. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See the comment by @PierU . I read too quickly: yours is precisely a case where OMP simd can do more than compiler simd.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout. Hi, Victor Eijkhout. I am so embarrassedto know that there is difference between OMP simd and compilor simd just after your lastest comments. In fact, I am an engineer doing mechanic calculation, not computering science. I compose a subroutine, and I want to call it in the vertorized manner, and that is why I posed this question here. The data to be passed to my subroutine have already been arranged in the array allignement, and the data are alse already in an OMP parallel calculation. What I need to do is to compose a SIMDed subroutine within each thread organized by OMP.

Comment: There is no conceptual difference. But a compiler is not always able to automatically identify what can be vectorized in some complex cases. OpenMP simd directives can be seen as an help that you give to the compiler: "please try vectorizing this part of the code". Note the "try": this is not because you think it can be vectorized that it can be vectorized, or efficiently vectorized.

Comment: @PierU. I have tried several cases:
(1) flags"-fopenmp -O/-O1-O2" togeter with the directives "!$OMP simd" does work! it can help reduce about half calculation time cost.
(2) flags"-fopenmp -O3" with get both conditions optimized with simd, since it shows no difference in view of time cost.
(3) calculation time cost can be different if the subroutine is in a module or in an explicit   interface.
Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: I have removed the if construct, leaving only algorhthmic calcuation. if the if construct is still there, no improvement, sadly.

Comment: It is expected that the `if` contruct break the vectorization. Could please post an answer with your updated code, the compilation options you used, and the obtained speed-up? This is perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question (and even to accept it), and it may help other people.

Answer (score 0):

```
      program test
        implicit none
        integer(8) i, int_time, end_time, n, q, j
        parameter ( n = 400, q = 80000 )
        real(8),dimension(n)::value_0, value_1, value_2, value_3
        real(8) ramdom_num
        ! declare the interface of the subroutine
        interface
          subroutine  iteration_test_simd (val_in1,val_in2,val_out)
          real(8), intent(in)  :: val_in1,val_in2
          real(8), intent(out) :: val_out
          end subroutine  iteration_test_simd
        end interface
        ! prepare the data that are to be used
        do i = 1, n
            call random_seed()
            call random_number(ramdom_num)
            value_0(i) = real(ramdom_num,8)
            value_1(i) = value_0(i)
            value_2(i) = 0.0d0
            value_3(i) = 0.0d0
        enddo
        ! check the system time for vetorized program
        call system_clock(int_time)
        do j = 1, q
        !$OMP simd!there in fact should be no space from the left
          do i = 1, n
            call iteration_test_simd(value_0(i), value_1(i), value_2(i))
          enddo
        enddo
        !$end omp simd !there in fact should be no space from the left
        call system_clock(end_time)
        write(*,*) sum(value_2)
        write(*,*) "Vetorized CPU time:",(end_time - int_time)/10
        ! check the system time for serialized program
        call system_clock(int_time)
        do j = 1, q
          do i = 1, n
            call iteration_test_serialized(value_0(i), value_1(i),
     1      value_3(i))
          enddo
        enddo
        call system_clock(end_time)
        write(*,*) sum(value_3)
        write(*,*) "Serialized CPU time:",(end_time - int_time)/10
       end program test

      ! subroutine for simded subroutine
      subroutine iteration_test_simd(val_in1,val_in2,val_out)
      !$omp declare simd(iteration_test_simd) !there in fact should be no space from the left
            implicit none
            real(8),intent(in)::val_in1,val_in2
            real(8),intent(out)::val_out
            val_out = val_in1+ val_in2
            !if (val_out .gt. 1.2d30) then
            !  val_out = 1.2d30
            !endif
            return
        end subroutine iteration_test_simd


      subroutine iteration_test_serialized(val_in1,val_in2,val_out)
      ! subroutine for scalared subroutine
            implicit none
            real(8) val_in1,val_in2,val_out
            val_out = val_in1+ val_in2
            !if (val_out .gt. 1.2d30) then
             ! val_out = 1.2d30
            !endif
            return
         end subroutine iteration_test_serialized
```

remarks:

(1) compile the codes with flags "-fopenmp -O/-O1/-O2", the time is half reduced with the "!$omp simd" directive (~ 7800 v.s. 15000).

(2) compile the codes with flags "-fopenmp -O3", the time is almost the same (~7500), which means that -O3 could contain the potential property of "simd" directive.

(3) if the "if" construct in each subroutine is not commented, no calculation time difference between serialized and vectorized program whichever -O, -O1, -O2 or -O3 is used, and sometimes the efficiency could be worse with the "simd" directive. However, cpu time is different in the view of -O, -O1, -O2 or -O3 for either serialized or vectorized program.

Comment: If this is indeed the answer that solved your problem, please explain what you did. Even very shortly, but at least the main point.

Comment: *"which means that -O3 could contain the potential property of "simd" directive."* At -O3 the compiler tries to apply many kinds of optimizations, including vectorizations. If the subroutines are in the same source file, there could be higher likelihood of inlining in which case the compiler can do the optimizations easier. Otherwise, link-time optimizations could help. Note that in modern Fortran, all subroutines should be inside a module or internal.

Comment: When it times to finding out whether vectorization was done, compilers have reporting flags for this purpose. Intel has `-qopt-report-phase=vec -qopt-report=1` and `-qopt-report-phase=vec -qopt-report=2` See, for example, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/fortran-compiler/tutorial-auto-vectorization/18-0/generating-a-vectorization-report-001.html

Comment: Unfortunately, in my tests at `-O3` the compiler is clever enough to find out that it does not have to do the `q` loop at all and does it just once. This is not a good test case. The subroutine or the loop should do something more useful to make a meaningful test case.

Comment: gcc/gfortran `-O3` enables `-ftree-vectorize`, auto-vectorization in general, not just for loops with OpenMP pragmas.  If you want it to use newer extensions supported by your CPU (but maybe not run on other people's computers), use `gfortran -O3 -march=native -fopenmp`.  And perhaps `-ffast-math` if your algorithm doesn't have a problem with those optimizations; treating FP math as if it were associative allows vectorization of loops like summing an FP array without needing OpenMP.